# Is there a WMD-like WYSIWIG Editor that supports Markdown Extra?

Tags: markdown, wmd-editor, wmd-markdown

I have some editor pages in my CMS that use the WMD control for inputting and displaying content written in Markdown.

We have now switched to Markdown Extra (because we needed tables) but WMD can't handle the new syntax to support tables. Is there a way of h4cking WMD to make it work with ME or should I give this up as a bad job?

Answer (score 1):

[Try the MarkdownDeep Javascript edition](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/dingus).

Turn on the PHP Extra compatibility mode with this line:

```
markdown.ExtraMode = true;
```

[This page](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/api) has more info on how to use the tool.

---

[image]

---